# What's the correct JSON structure when we have fields with flags?

Tags: json, rest, api

We have to return a object with data about user configuration. Some fields have a property indicating if this field is locked, if it's mandatory, etc.

What's the right structure for return this object in as JSON? We have consider

Option 1:

```
{
    "id": "123456",
    "config":{
        "field1" : "some-value",
        "field2" : true,
        "field3" : 23.1,
        "locked-fields" : ["field1", "field3"],
        "mandatory-fields" : ["field2", "field3"]
    },
    "data" : {
        "data-section-1":{
            "data-field1" : "some-value",
            "data-field2" : "some-value",
            "locked-fields" : ["data-field1"],
            "mandatory-fields" : ["data-field2"]
        },
        "data-section-2":{
            "data-field3" : "some-value",
            "data-field4" : "some-value",
            "locked-fields" : ["data-field3", "data-field4"]
       }
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
{
    "id": "123456",
    "config":{
        "field1" : { "value" : "some-value", "locked" : true, "mandatory" : false},
        "field2" : { "value" : true, "locked" : false, "mandatory" : true},
        "field3" : { "value" : 23.1, "locked" : true, "mandatory" : true}
    },
    "data" : {
        "data-section-1":{
            "data-field1" : { "value" : "some-value", "locked" : true, "mandatory" : false},
            "data-field2" : { "value" : "some-value", "locked" : false, "mandatory" : true}
        },
        "data-section-2":{
            "data-field3" : { "value" : "some-value", "locked" : true, "mandatory" : false},
            "data-field4" : { "value" : "some-value", "locked" : true, "mandatory" : false}
        }
    }
}
```

Which is the most correct?

Comment: Both are equally correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose option 2.

"Locked" or "Mandatory" are for me some kind of properties which object (`Field` in that case) has. Second Json represents "locked" and "mandatory" as such properties of `Field` object, so it looks better.